# Want to delete users from the four tables but user ids in the excel sheet, is it possible with PL/SQL

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am very new in the PL/SQL development, and basically I have 200 users in the excel sheet and we are  using SQL developer 3.0. I need to delete all 200 users from the 4 tables.

So first i have excel sheet(in which all login_ids mentioned)
Second i want to create PL/SQL code in which all queries will be run.

Example:

```
Declare    
{    
  Begin    
  delete from users (table) where id=(excel sheet login_id)    
  delete from hierarchy(table) where id=(excel sheet login_id)    
  delete  from data (table) where id=(excel sheet login_id)    
  delete from source(table) where id=(excel sheet login_id)    
}

END
```

So please let me know how i can fetch all the 200 login_ids from the excel sheet to my PL/SQ L code. We can do these steps manually but we want to create automation things so please let me know is this possible with PL/SQL code or other option like Vba code is efficient or helpful to maintain automation type.

And also in the PL/SQL code can we delete users from the Active directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can create some temporary table, upload all ids there and then just reference it by using:

```
where id in (select id from temporary_table);
```

Other choice whould be creating a long list of all ids and feeding it to the query:

```
where id in ("first", "second", "etc");
```